# Select options are not visible

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate a select option with values from a database and I followed the instructions from [here](https://thisinterestsme.com/populate-dropdown-list-mysql/).
My select menu seems to be populated but the options are invisible. According to the number of invisible lines, it's probably correct, but how can I made it visible?
My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php 
    try {
      $conn = new PDO('sqlite:db/Ciupercomania.db');
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE idattribute='10' ORDER by attributevalueEN ASC");
      $stmt->execute();
      $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ?>
    <select id="mushtype" name="mushtype" >
    <option value="*" selected>Mushroom types</option>
    <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php $row['idattributevalue']; ?>"><?php $row['attributevalueEN']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
      <?php 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
      ?>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

my database looks like this:
[image: database capture]
and the created select field is:
[image: Select menu]

Comment: You forgot `echo`: `<?php $row['idattributevalue']; ?>` should be `<?php echo $row['idattributevalue']; ?>`

Comment: Or you can use the short tag: `<?= $row['idattributevalue']; ?>`

Comment: indeed i forgot about echo, thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['idattributevalue']; ?>"><?php echo $row['attributevalueEN']; ?></option>
```

OR:

```
<option value="<?=$row['idattributevalue']; ?>"><?=$row['attributevalueEN']; ?></option>
```

If you enable

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in your php.ini file.

To enable "short tag" without editing php.ini file use

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
```

on top of your project.